# javascript regular expression to return an array of values embedded in a document string

Tags: javascript, regex

So I don't really get the nuances (or even the basics) of Regex's so I'm just gonna ask if anyone can produce a Javascript Regex that goes through the following string, does the item/ regex and returns an array of [4,378,382]:

```
var tmp_str="here is <a href='/arc/item/4'>item - more item stuff</a> and there are other things <a href='/arc/item/378'>another item - more item stuff</a> and finally <a href='/arc/item/382'>last item - more item stuffvar </a>"
```

I'll gladly upvote any correct answer.

I think something like (but clearly doesn't work):

```
var myRe = /item\/(b+)\'/g;
var myArray = myRe.exec(tmp_str);
// myArray should have the values
```

Help me Stack Overflow peeps, you're my only hope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\d` to match digit:

```
tmp_str.match(/item\/\d+/g)
// => ["item/4", "item/378", "item/382"]
tmp_str.match(/item\/\d+/g).map(function(m) { return m.substr(5); })
// => ["4", "378", "382"]
tmp_str.match(/item\/\d+/g).map(function(m) { return m.match(/\d+/)[0] })
// => ["4", "378", "382"]
```

Comment: amazing, thx so much. have to wait a few to accept. my sanity is safe.

Comment: @falsetru, is it possible to use non capturing group (?:) for `item` section?

Comment: @Ergec, Of course, it is possible. But I didn't use any backreference. So it will not make any difference.

Comment: @falsetru, if possible, could you please give that example too, just for future reference

Comment: @Ergec, `tmp_str.match(/(?:item\/)\d+/g).map(function(m) { return m.match(/\d+/)[0] })` ??